# create or update a panel in Grafana using Python

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I have a dashboard named as "server-plots" and there is another dashboard named as "master-plots". panels under "master-plots" are most updated graphs and I want to add the new panels inside "master-plots" dashboard to "server-plots" as well, everything with Python code (not manually or using curl).
I am able to programmatically take the backup of these plots using Grafana GET APIs ,as JSON. I want to find the new panels inside the "master-plots" dashboard JSON and add those into "server-plots" dashboard , all using Python. I am unable to find any API to do that. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I achieved this was by taking the backup of the `master-plots` as JSON using:

```
/api/dashboards/uid/<uid of the dashboard>
```

Then comparing it with the one inside the `server-plots` (taken similarly), and then updating the `server-plots` JSON with the diff (basically replacing `server-plots` JSON with the `master-plots` JSON), and finally writing that to the following using the `POST` method:

```
/api/dashboards/db/
```

One thing to consider here: The new JSON which is being written into the `server-plots` should have different `uid` and `overwrite=True`:

```
--snip--
f = open(myjsonfile,)  # the updated JSON of server-plots
data = json.load(f)
data["dashboard"]["id"] = None
data["overwrite"] = True
data["folderId"] = 123 # this is the folder ID of the server-plots
data["dashboard"]["uid"] = <logic to generate randum alpha-num>
url = "https://mygrafanaurl.com/api/dashboards/db"
headers = {'Authorization': 'auth',   'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```